# Make Python Gensim Search Functions Efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gensim

I have a DataFrame that has a text column. I am splitting the DataFrame into two parts based on the value in another column. One of those parts is indexed into a gensim similarity model. The other part is then fed into the model to find the indexed text that is most similar. This involves a couple of search functions to enumerate over each item in the indexed part. With the toy data, it is fast, but with my real data, it is much too slow using `apply`. Here is the code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')

d = {'number': [1,2,3,4,5], 'text': ['do you like python', 'do you hate python','do you like apples','who is nelson mandela','i am not interested'], 'answer':['no','yes','no','no','yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_yes = df[df['answer']=='yes']

df_no = df[df['answer']=='no']
df_no = df_no.reset_index()

docs = df_no['text'].tolist()
genDocs = [[w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(text)] for text in docs]
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(genDocs)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(genDoc) for genDoc in genDocs]
tfidf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)
sims = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(tfidf[corpus], num_features=len(dictionary))

def search(row):
    query = [w.lower() for w in word_tokenize(row)]
    query_bag_of_words = dictionary.doc2bow(query)
    query_tfidf = tfidf[query_bag_of_words]
    return query_tfidf

def searchAll(row):
    max_similarity = max(sims[search(row)])
    index = [i for i, j in enumerate(sims[search(row)]) if j == max_similarity]
    return max_similarity, index

df_yes = df_yes.copy()

df_yes['max_similarity'], df_yes['index'] = zip(*df_yes['text'].apply(searchAll))
```

I have tried converting the operations to dask dataframes to no avail, as well as python multiprocessing. How would I make these functions more efficient? Is it possible to vectorize some/all of the functions?

Comment: This should probably be on code review and not StackOverflow since the code works but it needs to be more efficient. Would have better luck there since we are here to mostly debug problems in non-functional code.

Comment: I created a question over there - thank you for the suggestion. Should I close/delete this one?

Comment: No I wouldn't just incase someone comes along with a good solution. But if you start to get flags/downvotes then I would for the sake of your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's intent and operation is very unclear. Assuming it works, explaining the ultimate goal, and showing more example data, more example queries, and the desired results in your question could help.

Perhaps it could be improved to not repeat certain operations over and over. Some ideas could include:

- only tokenize each row once, and cache the tokenization
- only `doc2bow()` each row once, and cache the BOW representation
- don't call `sims(search[row])` twice inside `searchAll()`
- don't iterate twice – once to find the max, then again to find the index – but just once

(More generally, though, efficient text keyword search often uses specialized reverse-indexes for efficiency, to avoid a costly iteration over every document.)

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts! And I agree - there is unneeded repetition. Would you be willing to share any approaches to tackling the issues you presented? Here is the Code Review question if it makes more sense to post there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213387/optimize-application-of-python-gensim-search-functions. In addition, do you have any more information on reverse-indexes? Finally, I'm not sure what I could add to make the question better - I think it is a small, reproducible example. Since desired results is simply faster execution, the data would stay the same.

Comment: I made some improvements based on your suggestions - posted them to the Code Review question. Do you mind sharing more on the second and fourth bullet points? I think doc2bow is being call only once for each row in the current function.

Comment: It's unclear what the motivation is of someone attempting such a query. What are they trying to find and why? Do they want one result or (as is more common in scored-search) a list of top results? What even does it mean to "search" a single row? (There's only one result possible, that one row! I'd find it clearer for a function that scores a single row against a query, returning a single number, to take two arguments, the query and row-candidate, and be called `score()`.)

Comment: I might be able to take a look at your other Q later, but note it'd be easier to review if the question were edited to provide one, single best example of your current code. Following a 1st rough attempt, then two incremental attempts-at-improvement, is more work for reviewers. And still, a clear statement of the ultimate user-needs, totally independent of the implementation choices ("DataFrame", "TFIDF", etc), can help determine if things are even on the right track.

Comment: The goal is to compare each row in `df_yes` with the `sims` index (which consists of all rows from `df_no`. So the function is applied to each row in `df_yes` and, for each row, find the maximum similarity value and index(ices) of `df_no`. I'll up date my CR question - thank you!

Comment: Why does anyone want to "compare each row in `df_yes` with the sims index (which consists of all rows from `df_no`)"? What is the ultimate benefit received by some user who doesn't care about rows, sims-indexes, etc?

Comment: To compare text similarities between two groups of text. Imagine a movie plot summary dataset. Some of the movies are comedies, the rest are unknown. The comedies are indexed, the rest are compared to that index to determine if there are any comedies among them.

Comment: Hate to be the 3-year-old playing "Why?", but, why does someone want "to compare text similarities between groups of text"? Do they want to know that one set of 10 movies is like another set of 20 movies? (And if so, why?) Or, do they have one movie they like and want to find N others like it? Or, are they typing a free-form description & trying to find other movies? (Also: wanting to this sort of info-retrieval (or similarity-analysis) at scale would usually want to leave the overhead of Pandas dataframes behind.)

Comment: No worries - completely understand/appreciate the "whys"! They want to take all the movies that are not defined as comedies, and find any movies among them that are comedies. They know they like the set of 20 comedies, now they want to find the comedy(ies) out of that set of 20 that are most similar to each of the 10 mystery-movies. If the similarity between a mystery-movie and a comedy is .85, there might be a good chance that they will like the movie. Obviously this is not the real scenario, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Also, I would love to optimize outside of pandas - definitely the sort of insight/help I am looking for. The reason I keep everything in pandas is because original data is coming from a relational database, and results have to be written back to that database. I suppose there could be ways to use pandas only at the entry/exit points.